# Still logged in after deleting Cookies and Session Storage

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, session-cookies, chromium, session-variables

I have seen the following behaviour with at least two webpages so far using Chromium browsers, no idea whether this is the same for Firefox browsers:

When I hit Clear Site Data in the DevTools while logged into the webpage within the specific tab -> Close all Tabs of that webpage, I expect to be logged out, as it is usual with the majority of webpages. However, on some very few one's the Cookie Consent Banner appears again, but I am still logged in.

Even after deleting every single Cookie and Session Storage entry manually via the DevTools and restarting the whole browser, I am still logged in. Finally, only a sign out on the webpage itself or deleting the whole browserdata (not only for the specific webpage) via Strg + H really signs me out. Well, despite the deletion of the browser data is no real sign out, but it vanishes the token from the client.

So, what I am no wondering with these webpages, where is the login data stored? Is there something different besides Localstorage, Cookies and Session Storage that only gets deleted via the general delete browser data function of the browser?

Comment: That can be cookies and storage of another site and you don't clear another site's cookies. For example example.com can use oauth.example.com for user authentication.